# Magento 2: How to disable or remove Product SKU field in the admin panel

Tags: magento2.3, adminhtml, products, admin-panel, custom-admin-grid

Magento 2: How to disable or remove Product SKU field in the admin panel
see image below for more clarification.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating a custom module.

Create below required files for the module under below path:

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml
```

Create `di.xml` file under `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml` with below content.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sku" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Attributes</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1000</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

And create `Attributes.php` file under `app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/` with below content.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;

class Attributes extends AbstractModifier
{
    /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager
     */
    private $arrayManager;

    /**
     * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        ArrayManager $arrayManager
    ) {
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }

    /**
     * modifyData
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * modifyMeta
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $attribute = 'sku'; //attribute code to disable
        $path = $this->arrayManager->findPath($attribute, $meta, null, 'children');
        $meta = $this->arrayManager->set(
            "{$path}/arguments/data/config/disabled",
            $meta,
            true
        );

        return $meta;
    }
}
```

This will disable the attribute.

After placing module in your Magento directory, you need to run the below commands to enable the module.

```
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d
php bin/magento c:f
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: facing an issue when i run that command php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module. The error coming is There are no commands defined in the "module" namespace.

Comment: From where you've run the command?? 

Follow this guide to enable the module on the website https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/enable-module.html

Comment: I run from Magento root directory and other commands not working as well like (php bin/magento cache:flush) when i delete that folder(Vendor) from app/code then everything working fine and commands also working as well.

Comment: OK, you need to change the Vendor and module folder name. Also in the file I've shared

Comment: Yes, Brother, I tried and it's working fine. I have one more question about how we can write a custom CSS for admin panel? For example, I want to hide add product button how I can hide using CSS.

Comment: That's great.

Also, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612475/magento-2-adding-custom-css-to-admin-backend and add .catalog-product-index.page-layout-admin-1column button#add_new_product-button { display: none; } in the added CSS file.

Comment: @Sumit, how can we remove it, I have created a custom attribute with group, just need to remove it if my module is not enabled.

Comment: @jafarpinjar By this way, you can disable the product attribute. For removing the attribute, I'm not sure but I think you need to run a setup script when the module is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can make it not Editable as:

Create file in Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_edit_action">
        <observer name="vendor_admin_lock" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ProductLockAttributes" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create file in Vendor/Module/Observer/ProductLockAttributes.php:

```
class ProductLockAttributes implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $product = $event->getProduct();
        $product->lockAttribute('sku');
        $product->lockAttribute('sku_type');
    }
}
```

Comment: These files i have to make in app/code ?

Comment: Yes exactly, you can add this in your existing module or create new one.